# Fedora 30: How to create dual boot with Windows 7?

Tags: fedora, grub2, dual-boot, grub2-mkconfig

I have read through all the similar questions here on SE and I am not seeing an answer to my question.

My workstation currently has Fedora 30 running and grub2 installed.  This is pure BIOS, no EFI in sight.

Here is my disk configuration:

```
/dev/sda1 - ext4 (boot)
/dev/sda2 - lvm (Fedora 30)
/dev/sda3 - ntfs (Windows 7)
```

os-prober is working fine as it found the Windows7 partition accurately and quickly.  However, when I select Windows7 in grub it says "Setting Partition Type to 0x7" and then hangs.  Fedora boots fine.

I have been running Fedora for a long time and just over the weekend installed Windows. It overwrote my boot configuration during Windows install (which I knew I would) so I booted a live image of Fedora and re-ran `grub2-install` and `grub2-mkconfig`.  I checked that the partition uuid from blkid matches the uuid in the grub.cfg file.

I suspect I am missing some metadata somewhere which is preventing Windows from booting but I am not sure where else to look.

Comment: Did you delete the Windows 7 boot files in its boot partition, before copying them into the NTFS partition? Grub only boots working Windows. So you may need to run Windows repairs, which will probably restore Windows boot loader to MBR. And then restore grub to MBR. But best not to use Windows 7 anymore unless not on Internet as EoL - end of life.

Comment: I actually kept the Win7 boot partition around (/dev/sda4).  It is possible to copy the contents over?   Win7 is being used for an AppSec training demo and is not really germane to the conversation.

Comment: If missing boot files, you need a Windows repair disk or Windows 7 installer with the repair console. Vista,  win7 and newer Windows in BIOS boot mode
  Boot files/dirs:   /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

Comment: @oldfred I will give that a try.  I ran the repair console tools once and nothing happened.  Fortunately, it didn't try to create a new MBR.

Comment: Is boot bcd necessary?  It lists the installations and their locations.  In this case, I just want the bootloader to run since grub2 has already shown where Windows is installed.

Comment: The BCD is required for Windows boot, but grub looks for files not Windows boot flag and if you do not have bootmgr & /boot/BCD, I do not think grub finds Windows.

Comment: grub2 is finding my two windows partitions (sda3 and 4) but once I select one of them it says "Setting Partition Type to 0x7" and then hangs.  I suspect files are missing.  I am going to mount them on Linux and check.  My other computer has an identical setup - the one for the classroom lab work - and it boots beautifully into Windows from grub2.